# I want to avoid dynamic pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-pivot

I am using dynamic pivot like this

```
declare @pivot varchar(max)
declare @column varchar(max)

SELECT @column= ISNULL(@column + ',','') +
       QUOTENAME(METRIC_CD)
       FROM (select Distinct METRIC_CD from  EFRDS.FCT_STAFF_METRIC f join EFRDS.DIM_SCORE_METRIC  m on f.METRIC_KEY=m.METRIC_KEY) AS Courses

declare  @column1 varchar(max)

select @column1= ISNULL(@column1 ,'') + 'Max('+QUOTENAME(METRIC_CD)+ ') as '+QUOTENAME(METRIC_CD)+','
       FROM (select Distinct METRIC_CD from  EFRDS.FCT_STAFF_METRIC f join EFRDS.DIM_SCORE_METRIC  m on f.METRIC_KEY=m.METRIC_KEY) AS Courses
       set @column1= STUFF(@column1,len(@column1),1,'')

set @pivot='select school_year ,YEAR_KEY,DISTRICT_KEY,SCHOOL_KEY,TEAM_KEY,STAFF_KEY,min_score,max_Score,'+@column1+' 
from
(
select f.*,METRIC_CD,m.SCHOOL_YEAR
from EFRDS.FCT_STAFF_METRIC f
join EFRDS.DIM_SCORE_METRIC  m on f.METRIC_KEY=m.METRIC_KEY
)p
pivot(sum(value) for METRIC_CD in('+@column+')) as pvt 
group by school_year ,YEAR_KEY,DISTRICT_KEY,SCHOOL_KEY,TEAM_KEY,STAFF_KEY,min_score,max_Score' 
exec (@pivot)
```

instead of using

```
pivot(sum(value) for METRIC_CD in('+@column+')) as pvt
```

I want to use

```
pivot(sum(value) for METRIC_CD in (  select ISNULL(@column + ',','') +
               QUOTENAME(METRIC_CD)
               FROM (select Distinct METRIC_CD from  EFRDS.FCT_EVALUATE_METRICS f join EFRDS.DIM_SCORE_METRIC ) m on f.METRIC_KEY=m.METRIC_KEY) as g
```

But I am facing this problem

> incorrect syntax near 'select'.expecting '.',ID, or Quoted_id.